# Pointer operand on declared int vs a declared pointer

Tags: c, variables, pointers

I am confused

What is happening in this code snippet:

```
int *a;
a = 1;
*a = 1;
```

Versus this one:

```
int b;
b = 2;
*b = 2;
```

Comment: You may not write `int` with a capitalized initial.

Comment: For starters, neither of those works. They probably don't even compile.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: @KeithThompson I was more looking to put the concepts into words, and you did that for me. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int *a;
a = 1;
*a = 1;
```

`a` is a pointer, so the assignment `a = 1` is invalid. (In C standard terms, it's a "constraint violation", requiring a diagnostic.) Your compiler *must* print at least a warning for this assignment; it *should* reject it altogether. (Some compilers may insert an implicit conversion, as if you had written `a = (int*)1`; you should not depend on that.)

```
int b;
b = 2;
*b = 2;
```

`b` is not a pointer, so `*b` is invalid. Again, your compiler *must* diagnose the error, and *should* reject your program.

In both cases, the code has no defined meaning in C.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a slightly different tack from Keith and the rest...

In the first case, you've declared `a` as a pointer to `int`; this means that the variable `a` is meant to hold the *address* of an integer object in memory.  Assigning a new value to `a` means you're telling `a` to point to a different object; assigning a new value to `*a` means you're writing a new value to the thing `a` points to.

As Keith and the others have mentioned, you can't directly assign a non-zero integer value to a pointer object; the types aren't compatible.  If you had written

```
a = (int *) 1;
```

then you'd be saying you want `a` to point to the integer object starting at address `0x00000001`, which is not likely to be a valid memory address on most platforms for a number of reasons.  Writing

```
*a = 1;
```

means you want to assign the integer value 1 to the location *pointed to* by `a`; IOW, you're saying you want the integer object at address `0x00000001` to contain the integer value `1` (again, this most likely won't work; `0x00000001` is likely to be a "protected" address, and most systems like to align multi-byte data types on addresses that are multiples of 2 or 4).

In the second case, you've declared `b` to be an `int`; this means that the variable `b` is meant to hold a signed integer value.  Because `b` is not a pointer type, the expression `*b` is not valid; the compiler will reject that expression outright.

However, you can combine the two snippets like so:

```
int *a;
int b;
a = &b;
*a = 2;
```

The expression `&b` gives us the address of the variable `b`; the type of the expression is `int *`.  So we're storing the address of the variable `b` in the variable `a`.  We can then assign a value to `b` through the *expression* `*a`; `*a = 2;` is equivalent to `b = 2;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *a;
a = 1;
```

The last statement is not C. You cannot assign an integer value (except `0`) to a pointer object.

```
int b;
b = 2;
*b = 2;
```

The last statement is not C. You cannot dereference an object of an non-pointer type,

Answer (score 0):

The first one:

1. Declares `a` as a pointer to an `int`
2. Assigns it the value 2 (as an address)
3. Assigns 1 to the integer in address 2 in the memory space

The second:

1. Declares `b` as an `int`
2. Assigns it the value 2
3. Will be rejected by the compiler, since b is not of type *int

Either way, referencing (the `*` operator) a random int value is not a good idea and will probably crash your program.

Comment: Is implicit conversion from `int` to `int*` even legit? Edit: Nope, wont compile for me

Comment: Yeah, and both result in an access violation. First one will be recognized as acceptable by the compiler, but the second one will be taken as illegal.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: If a compiler accepts the first one without a warning, it's not a conforming C compiler.

Comment: @KeithThompson Acceptable doesn't necessarily mean issue-free.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: A conforming compiler may (and IMHO should) reject both. There is no implicit conversion from `int` to `int*` (except for the special case of a null pointer constant, which doesn't apply here). (gcc merely warns about the first by default, which is IMHO unfortunate.)